# Default cache used by Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, caching, web-applications

What is the name of the default cache used by Hibernate? Is there a default cache even, or do you have to add a cache provider in order to take advantage of a cache?

I thought it was the EHCache but I think this has to be configured...it is not "there" by default...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hibernate already provides a caching mechanisms called **1st level cache** by the persistent context . It is in the  [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) scoped , enabled by default and cannot be turned off.

The cache provider such as EHCache provides another caching mechanisms called  **2nd level cache** . It is in the  [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) scoped . No 2nd level cache is enable by default and you have to configure it .

See [this](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate) for how to enable EHCache in hibernate.

Comment: The link in this answer has gone stale.

Answer (score 3):

No second level cache is enabled in hibernate by default.

You can always choose one of these cache providers according to your needs:

- EHCache
- OSCache
- SwarmCache
- Jboss TreeCache
- JBoss Cache 2

You can always refer to hibernate documentation to see how to register it.