# what is the StandardQueryCache alternative in Hibernate 5.4.4

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I am using following code for Cache.

```
 public class SuiteStandardQueryCache extends StandardQueryCache {

    public SuiteStandardQueryCache(Settings settings, Properties props, UpdateTimestampsCache updateTimestampsCache, String regionName)
                                                                                                                                       throws HibernateException {
        super(settings, props, updateTimestampsCache, regionName);
    }

    public boolean put(QueryKey key, Type[] returnTypes, List result, boolean isNaturalKeyLookup, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException {
        if (isNaturalKeyLookup && result.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Long ts = new Long(session.getTimestamp());
            List cacheable = new ArrayList(result.size() + 1);
            cacheable.add(ts);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                if (returnTypes.length == 1) {
                    // cacheable.add( returnTypes[0].disassemble( result.get( i
                    // ), session, null ) );
                    Object resultObj = result.get(i);
                    if (resultObj instanceof Object[]) {
                        resultObj = ((Object[]) result.get(i))[0];
                    }
                    cacheable.add(returnTypes[0].disassemble(resultObj, session, null));
                } else {
                    cacheable.add(disassemble((Object[]) result.get(i), returnTypes, null, session, null));
                 }
            }
            getRegion().put(key, cacheable);
            return true;
        }
    }


    public static Serializable[] disassemble(final Object[] row,

        return disassembled;
    }
}
```

This code is hibernate for Hibernate 3, And I am going to upgrade it to Hibernate 5.4.4, in which this class is not present.

Please help to find out alternative for same.

Comment: It looks like this code was written to get around a specific problem or bug, possibly in an early version of Hibernate. You need to find out why this was written in the first place

Comment: @Guillaume It could be possible, But I am just looking for StandardQueryCache  class, what is the alternative for this class.

Answer (score 2):

The query cache can be configured using whatever 2nd level cache provider you choose. Hibernate has no 2nd level cache by default, you must configure and provide one ([Default cache used by Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349530/default-cache-used-by-hibernate)).

For example, I use EhCache as a 2nd level cache. I configure it via XML as follows:

```
<cache-template name="default">
    <key-type>java.lang.Object</key-type>
    <value-type>java.lang.Object</value-type>

    <expiry>
      <none/>
    </expiry>

    <heap unit="entries">100000</heap>
</cache-template>

<!-- Configure the caches that Hibernate uses by default. -->
<cache alias="default-query-results-region" uses-template="default" />
<cache alias="default-update-timestamps-region" uses-template="default" />
```

I believe the Java class used by this cache ends up being `org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache.Eh107Cache` because of my cache configuration.

If you want to add custom logic as per above, I believe what you want to do is set a custom caching provider for the `hibernate.javax.cache.provider` configuration property. My current value is `org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider`. Override that class to provide a cache manager which builds caches as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for answer that I can do, But I want to continue with previous code, just don't want to change in my code it might impact other area of application, I am looking for some code base alternative solution for StandardQueryCache , unfortunately I didn't get any clue for same.

Comment: What I am saying is there is no replacement as far as I can tell -- it just uses a standard cache (whichever you tell it). There is no dedicated query cache class.

Comment: Okay,  Where should I configure this, means which xml file would it be go, I am new to Hibernate :) And also please tell me about QueryCacheFactory interface this is also extracted from hibernate 5.4.4